# Feature Importance in Stacked Model

Tags: machine-learning, features, feature-importances, ensemble, stacking

I have built a stacked model using mlxtend StakingCVClassifier. I want to know the feature importance scores now. Is there any way I can calculate feature importance scores for the stacked model? If not can I combine the feature importance of individual models somehow?  I have tried SHAP values but StakingCVClassifier doesn't support that. Stacked model has RF, LightGBM , and MLP. Please let me know what are the possible solutions.